# JsonArray : how to update only one field and save back to same file

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing

How can I take the only product object from below request and update the date to current date and save it back to json file with updated dates.

I have this file as a json file on my machine. Any help would be appreciated. I used JsonArray but I could not able to make complete logic.

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "test": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "string"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "product": {
                "id": "12345",
                "date": "2019-04-09T13:15:39.253Z",
                "Address": []
            },
            "Moreitems": [
                {
                    "id": "qwerty123",
                    "product": {
                        "id": "qwerty345",
                        "date": "2019-04-09T13:16:43.755Z",
                        "Address": []
                    },
                    "Moreitems": [
                        {
                            "id": "abcd123",
                            "product": {
                                "id": "abcd789",
                                "date": "2019-04-09T13:17:37.151Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my code: in content string object, I read the content of json file

```
      `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content.toString());
        JSONArray x=(JSONArray) obj.get("items");
        JSONArray y=(JSONArray) x.getJSONObject(0).get("MoreItems");
        for(int i=0;i<y.length();i++) {
             obj2 = (JSONObject) y.getJSONObject(i).get("product");

            OffsetDateTime date = 
  OffsetDateTime.parse(obj2.get("date").toString());

            if(localdate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {               
                date2 = date.plusMonths((localdate.getMonthValue()) - 
   date.getMonthValue());                   
            }
            if(localdate.getYear() != date2.getYear()) {
        date3 = date2.plusYears((localdate.getYear()) - date2.getYear());
            }
            //System.out.prawsxintln(date3.toString());
            obj2.put("date", date3.toString());
            y.put(i, obj2);
        }`
```

Comment: Would be great if you can show us what you have done so far..

Comment: added the code.

Comment: does nesting in your json file keep increasing ? if its fixed then I can provide a solution.

Comment: @Vignesh_A, it will not increase, it is fixed. Can you please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the field from the json and again add it back. I have done it for 2 levels, you can replicate the same for third level. you need to through each level of nesting to make this change. in the below sample I have replace date with "add new date". you can replace with whatever value you require.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class datatest {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("/Desktop/SO.json")));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray nesting0 = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
        JSONObject items = (JSONObject) nesting0.get(0);
        JSONObject product1 = (JSONObject) items.get("product");
        product1.remove("date");
        product1.put("date", "add new date");
       JSONArray moreItems1 = (JSONArray) items.get("Moreitems");
       JSONObject moreItems1Obj = (JSONObject) moreItems1.get(0);
       JSONArray moreItems2 = (JSONArray) 
        moreItems1Obj.get("Moreitems");
       JSONObject product2 = (JSONObject) moreItems1Obj.get("product");
       product2.remove("date");
       product2.put("date", "add new date");

    File file = new File("/Desktop/SOO.json");
    DataOutputStream outstream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
           outstream.write(obj.toString().getBytes());
                outstream.close();
    }
}
```